# Jquery tigger click event of file control on click of link not working

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I want to open a file chooser dialogbox on click on link, my code is as below:

```
<a href="#" onclick="OpenFileDialogue();">
    <img src="xyz.jpeg">
    <input type="file" style="display: none" id="UploadProfPic" />
</a>

<script>
    function OpenFileDialogue(){
        $("#UploadProfPic").click();        
    }    
</script>
```

**Error: Too much recursion**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is within the link (which is also not correct syntax), so when you trigger a click on the input it propagates to the link. Place the `input` tag outside of the `a` tag to fix the issue:

```
<a href="#" onclick="OpenFileDialogue();">
    <img src="xyz.jpeg">
</a>
<input type="file" style="display: none" id="UploadProfPic" />
```